# In the PPO objective function, does the expectation do a weighted average over the batch?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, proximal-policy-optimization

I am currently working on implementing Proximal Policy Optimization (PPO) for a reinforcement learning task, and I have a few questions regarding the objective function and probability calculations.

1. In the PPO objective function, $$L(\theta) = E\left[\min \left(r(\theta) \cdot A, \text{clip}(r(\theta), 1 - \epsilon, 1 + \epsilon) \cdot A \right)\right]$$ does the expectation $E$ do a weighted average over the batch? If so, how are these weights determined?
2. When calculating the ratio function $$r(\theta) = \frac{\pi_{\text{new}}(a|s)}{\pi_{\text{old}}(a|s)}$$ would $r(\theta)$ be a single value or a whole array with probability distribution length?

I appreciate any clarification on these points, as it would greatly help me in understanding the nuances of PPO and implementing it effectively.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: One question per post. Split this post into multiple ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for putting all my questions in one post.

After careful searching, this is the answer to all the questions:

1. The expectation notation means mean average.
2. $r(\theta)$ does element-wise division of new policy and old policy probability distribution.